# How can I pass an actual javascript array dynamically rather than manually in an eventListener? (FullCalendar)

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I've taken straight from the documentation the event section code showing how you would have the event code if passing multiple sources and multiple events. This looks fantastic except I have no clue how to make this generate dynamically. I get a query from a DB with data in php, pass to a javascript array and need to print the results in the appropriate tags for x amount of rows returned.

Any attempt of mine to do a while, for loop, or function, makes keyword variable inside them (like eventSource, event, Title, Start) become invalid and unreadable to the javascript, causing my calendar to crash. If it's meant to take arrays there has to be a way to generate this section dynamically? Appreciate any tips. Added comments to the place I'd like to "loop" or generate dynamically.

```
        <html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],

// I want to loop from here...
  eventSources: [

    // your event source
    {
      events: [ // put the array in the `events` property
        {
          title  : 'event1',
          start  : '2010-01-01'
        },
        {
          title  : 'event2',
          start  : '2010-01-05',
          end    : '2010-01-07'
        },
        {
          title  : 'event3',
          start  : '2010-01-09T12:30:00',
        }
      ],
      color: 'black',     // an option!
      textColor: 'yellow' // an option!
    }

    // any other event sources...

  ]
// to here. Passing an array I would have gotten from a database query
// with some integer that goes down until rows = 0
        });

        calendar.render();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can define a URL, or a function, or a variable, as the source in place of hard-coding the data. The documentation contains examples of different types of event definitions

Comment: It's just because it specifically cites this example as array that I figured there would be a dynamic way to do it. But I guess it's really explicitly for hard coded arrays? Is my best bet actually passing a function or perhaps even a json to make it dynamically? If I can avoid the json solution thought as my knowledge of that is zero and im short on time to crash course that component of javascript.

Comment: Well it depends exactly what you mean by "dynamic"? That's a pretty broad term. Can you explain how you want it to work in more detail? Where would the event data come from? Should they be loaded as soon as the calendar loads, or later on based on user input? Can the user press something to load a different set of events?

Comment: So what I mean by dynamic is basically that I run an SQL query and count the number of rows i get back. Then I want to create an event for every single one of those rows. Since it will vary per client ID getting queried, I need the event array to be dynamically generated. Let me know if you need more clarifications

Comment: When you say vary by client ID, do you mean the user selects the client ID on the screen and expects the calendar to re-populate with new events based on that updated selection? Or is it something pre-determined when the calendar loads, only affecting the parameters of the initial database query? (I did ask you about user input detail already above, but your explanation of the scenario was still not very precise)

Comment: The clientID is predetermined by a logged in user. I would pass that ID to the SQL on page load so they get data from their own personalized calendar. I don't really know how to clarify beyond for the dynamic bit. If you look at the example code. It has an array of 3 events hard coded manually inside an eventSource. I simply want to be able to generate that whole section dynamically (including eventSources). So if a user has 10 events to his name, there would be 10 eventSources.

Comment: Then I would suggest using the "events as JSON feed" pattern - there's a page about it in the documentation

Comment: I guess i've been woefully trying to cover my eyes on that one because I have no idea how JSON works and hoped I could shoehorn in a workaround. Had to learn it eventually ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would have used a comment for this but i don't have enough reputations to do that. 
From what i see, you are trying to add events dynamically after initializing the calendar but that cannot happen if you initialize the calendar inside DOMContentLoaded event. Doing that makes the calendar variable inaccessible to you because of the scope from which the code was run. What you should do (that worked form me) is to directly attach the calendar element and the calendar itself their respective variables without wrapping it inside the DOMContentLoaded event listener. so essentially your code will now look like this:

```
<script>
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ]});
</script>
```

Then you can add events dynamically by calling `calendar.addEvent()`

Comment: I think I see what you mean, i'm working inside the initialized content so I can't access the variables that way?

Comment: exactly. to access the calendar variable you have to define it globally at the script level, not inside a function call or event listeners